# Efficient way to check Geometry type and SRID of Table in Postgres Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm writing a postgres function to perform some spatial calculations.

I need to error catch incorrect geometries and mismatched SRID's from the two tables that are arguments to the function

the code below works but seems like a poor way to acheive this.

```
-- check the geometries in each table
EXECUTE format('SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(geom) FROM %s', master_table)
INTO master_type_holder;

IF master_type_holder != 'ST_Polygon' THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'master table geometries must be type ST_Polygon';
END IF;

EXECUTE format('SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(geom) FROM %s', ref_table)
INTO ref_type_holder;

IF ref_type_holder != 'ST_Polygon' THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Reference table geometries must be type ST_Polygon';
END IF;
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Would ST_isValid do the validation you want? https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html

Comment: and perhalps `ST_SRID(geom)` for checking the SRS? e.g. `SELECT ST_SRID('SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)'::geometry);`

Comment: It wouldn't. `ST_IsValid()` checks that the geometry conforms to the definition of the type that is specified, for instance, the boundary of a polygon can't cross through itself as seen in the example in the docs. I'm looking to check that the geometry in the table is `ST_Polygon` and not `ST_Linestring`

Comment: I see. In that case I believe you're doing it just right with ST_GeometryType :) Are you also looking for a way to automatically detect all tables containing geometries to perform your test?  `SELECT 
  attrelid::regclass AS table_name,
  attname            AS column_name,
  atttypid::regtype  AS datatype
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE atttypid::regtype::text = 'geometry'`

Comment: no there's separate code to handle table inputs correctly, thanks for that suggestion though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you expect all records to be of the same type, the fastest and safest would be to restrict the column to the proper type, and to simply ensure the column is of the proper type

```
CREATE TABLE test (id integer, geom geometry(polygon,4326));


SELECT * 
FROM geometry_columns 
WHERE f_table_name = 'test'
AND type = 'POLYGON' and srid = 4326;
```